# 2 Column Issue Height 100%

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to make a 2 column(sidebar) responsive theme for SMF forum software. I wanted to stick a column on the right that would expand 100% the height of it's parent.

FYI, I just started converting the default theme, into a responsive theme.

Usually, I don't have problems with these issues, or responsive design. However, I cannot figure out why the height of the sidebar, keeps matching the height of the header.

The sidebar HTML is outside the header HTML, and before it. Yet, when you give the sidebar say a fixed width of 400px via inspect element, it also expands the height of the header. I am baffled by this, as code-side it doesn't seem to make sense.

I figured if I had another set of eyes, someone can help me figure this out.

http://xarcms.com/index.php?theme=3

Thanks.

Comment: You would probably get better and more answers if you accepted more answers to your questions.

Comment: I will go back and and review my previous questions. I always voteup useful comments, but as far as I can remember, no one has actually provided a proper answer to any of my questions. Like I said though, I will go back and review...

Comment: I went back and accepted answers, even though those answers didn't really fix my issue, but were correct. There was only one question I asked that actually had the answer that fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this problem, I placed the  and  areas outside the div container. I was able to remove 4 un-needed divs(mostly wrappers) because of this. So In a rough nutshell...

Switched To This:

```
<div width wrapper>
<header></header>
<aside floated></aside>
<section></section>
<footer></footer>
</div>
```

Rather Than:

```
<div width wrapper>
<section>
<header></header>
<aside floated></aside>
<div></div>
<footer></footer>
</section>
</div>
```

Which seemed to be cleaner and make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

The main thing that I see is that you're styling the wrong element. You have your sidebar wrapped in an `<aside>`, which is not floated, nor does it have a size declared. The sidebar content that you have styled is, therefore, expanding to 100% the `<aside>` which itself is shrink-wrapping down to the size of the content. You need to shift your styles to the `<aside>` to get it to behave more correctly.

Aside from that, I don't have much else for you at the moment, but the above should get you started. From there, I'd double-check your CSS to make sure you're not getting too broad a scope on one of your styles. You might want to also look at your HTML structure and make sure that you only nest things down as far as absolutely necessary. If you're still having trouble, see if you can get a trimmed-down version that still shows the problem, so that we can more easily help you.

Comment: Further down the road, there will be more than one aside. Would is proper to add an id to the html5 tag(example: <aside id="side-panel">? I haven't seen anyone do that yet, so I figured there was a reason.

Comment: There's absolutely nothing wrong with adding IDs and classes to HTML5 elements. You probably don't see it happen often, because there's generally a reduced need to do so now, due to the tags themselves being more semantic ("aside" instead of "div class='aside'", or "nav" instead of "div class='nav'").

Comment: This is good news, as it will allow me to make things a little cleaner.

Comment: I was able to go back, and clean things up alot. Thanks.